# Tikz elements shift around a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I am implemented the following picture in tikz:

[image]

My tikz code is as followed:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw=black, fill=none, minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}, cross/.default={2pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.35, every node/.style = {scale = 0.6}]
%\draw[step=1,gray, ,very thin, opacity=.5] (-12,-12) grid (12,12);
\coordinate (center) at (0,0) node[thick,cross = 6pt, label={[black] above left:\huge BS}]{};
\draw[name path = circle1, dashed, blue] (center) circle[radius = 4.5];
\draw [name path = circle2, dashed, blue](center) circle[radius = 8];
\draw [name path = circle3, dashed, blue] (center) circle[radius = 12.5];

\path node (A) at ++(45.3:4.5) [thick,cross =  6pt, red]{};
\path node (C) at ++(90:12.5)[thick,cross = 6pt, red, label={[black] above right:\huge UE}]{};
\path node (B) at ++(78.4:8) [thick,cross= 6pt, red]{};
\path node (D) at ++(90:8){};
\path node (E) at ++(90:4.5){};
\path node (F) at ++(134.7:4.5) [thick,cross =  6pt, red, opacity = 0.6]{};
\path node (G) at ++(101.6:8) [thick,cross= 6pt, red, opacity = 0.6]{};
\draw[->, black](C) to node[above, xshift = 1em]{\Large $\Delta l$} (B);
\draw[->, black](B) -- node[above, xshift = 1em]{\Large $\Delta l$}(A);
\draw[->, black](C) to node[above, xshift = 1em, opacity = 0.6]{} (G);
\draw[->, black](G) -- node[above, xshift = 1em, opacity = 0.6]{}(F);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now what I am looking for is a way to rotate all the crosses inclusive labels, so that the shape (triangle) is rotated around the circle. Is there an easy way for it?

Comment: Like adding `rotate=30` option to the picture? For example, `[scale = 0.35, every node/.style = {scale = 0.6}, rotate=30]`

Comment: yeah but on the same time i want to keep the old picture

Comment: So I need to have an option which says: "This marked area should be rotated, the other not"

Comment: You don’t need ´tkz-euclide ´ to make this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should solve your problem. Maybe you still need to set the right anchor for labeling the edges (right, above, etc.).

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\tikzset{
    cross/.style={
        cross out,
        draw=black,
        fill=none,
        minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth),
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt
    },
    cross/.default={2pt},
}

\begin{document}
\foreach \rotate in {0,-5,...,-360} {% specify the rotations that you want
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale = 0.35,
        every node/.style = {scale = 0.6},
        arrow/.style={
            -Latex,
            black
        }
    ]
        % center point
        \node[thick, cross=6pt, label={[black] above left:\huge BS}] {};
        % circles
        \foreach \r in {4.5, 8, 12.5}
            \draw[dashed, blue] circle[radius = \r];
        % crosses
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\posA}{45.3+\rotate}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\posB}{78.4+\rotate}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\posF}{134.7+\rotate}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\posG}{101.6+\rotate}
        \foreach \labelName/\pos in {A/\posA:4.5, B/\posB:8, F/\posF:4.5, G/\posG:8}
            \node (\labelName) at ++(\pos) [thick,cross=6pt, red] {};
        % arrows
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\posC}{90+\rotate}
        \draw (\posC:12.5) node (C) [thick, cross=6pt, red, label={[black] above right:\huge UE}] {}
            edge[arrow] node[right] {\Large $\Delta l$} (B)
            edge[arrow] (G);
        \draw[arrow] (B) -- node[right] {\Large $\Delta l$} (A);
        \draw[arrow] (G) -- (F);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the `tkz-euclide` package:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\foreach \rotate in {0,-5,...,-360} {% specify the rotations that you want
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.35]
        % create bounding box
        \useasboundingbox (-15,-15) rectangle (15,15);

        % center point
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){BS}
        \tkzDrawPoint[shape=cross out, size=6pt, thick](BS)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above left=.125cm](BS)
        % circles
        \tkzDrawCircles[R,blue,dashed](BS,4.5cm BS,8cm BS,12.5cm)
        % crosses
        \foreach \angle/\radius/\name [evaluate=\angle as \computedAngle using \angle+\rotate] in {%
            90/12.5/UE,%
            45.3/4.5/A,%
            78.4/8/B,%
            134.7/4.5/F,%
            101.6/8/G%
        } {%
    %        \tkzDefPointOnCircle[radius = angle \computedAngle center BS radius \radius]% newer version (for example: 4.05b)
            \tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=\computedAngle, center=BS, radius=\radius]
            \tkzGetPoint{\name}
            \tkzDrawPoint[shape=cross out, red, size=6pt,thick](\name)
        }
        \tkzLabelPoints[above right=.125cm](UE)
        % arrows
        \tkzDrawSegments[-Latex](UE,B B,A)
        \tkzLabelSegment[right](UE,B){$\Delta l$}
        \tkzLabelSegment[right](B,A){$\Delta l$}
        \tkzDrawSegments[-Latex](UE,G G,F)
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: The solution creates (only) several pages. To generate several frames one can use for example the `animate` package (command `\multiframe`). Important, not all PDF readers can display the result. See the requirements in the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/animate) of the `animate` package.

Answer (score 2):

Direct use `animate` package, keep the original code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw=black, fill=none, minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}, cross/.default={2pt}}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls,autoplay,loop]{20}
\multiframe{120}{i=0+-3}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.35, every node/.style = {scale = 0.6}]
        % Create enough space for picture
        \path (-15.5,-15) rectangle (15.5,15);
        %\draw[step=1,gray, ,very thin, opacity=.5] (-12,-12) grid (12,12);
        \coordinate (center) at (0,0) node[thick,cross = 6pt, label={[black] above left:\huge BS}]{};
        \draw[name path = circle1, dashed, blue] (center) circle[radius = 4.5];
        \draw [name path = circle2, dashed, blue](center) circle[radius = 8];
        \draw [name path = circle3, dashed, blue] (center) circle[radius = 12.5];
        
        \path node (A) at ++(45.3+\i:4.5) [thick,cross =  6pt, red]{};
        \path node (C) at ++(90+\i:12.5)[thick,cross = 6pt, red, label={[black] above right:\huge UE}]{};
        \path node (B) at ++(78.4+\i:8) [thick,cross= 6pt, red]{};
        \path node (D) at ++(90:8){};
        \path node (E) at ++(90:4.5){};
        \path node (F) at ++(134.7+\i:4.5) [thick,cross =  6pt, red, opacity = 0.6]{};
        \path node (G) at ++(101.6+\i:8) [thick,cross= 6pt, red, opacity = 0.6]{};
        \draw[->, black](C) to node[above, xshift = 1em]{\Large $\Delta l$} (B);
        \draw[->, black](B) -- node[above, xshift = 1em]{\Large $\Delta l$}(A);
        \draw[->, black](C) to node[above, xshift = 1em, opacity = 0.6]{} (G);
        \draw[->, black](G) -- node[above, xshift = 1em, opacity = 0.6]{}(F);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}  
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Basic question if you don't mind: are the double plus signs mandatory here "\path node ( ) at ++( , )" and why? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Diaa I don't think so. Unless there are some nodes specified before that.